# How can I show the content of all pages (with links) on a single page?

Tags: pages

I want to display the content of all pages on a single page, with links to each page.

This might sound like a daft request, but it's useful for quickly reviewing what's available on a smallish site.

Using the code below, I can get most of the info I want, but don't know how to add the permalink.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages();
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
$title = $page_data->post_title;
$slug = $page_data->post_name;
echo $title;
echo $slug;
echo $content;}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to show list of page content. Page title will be the link of that page.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',    //specifying post type
    'posts_per_page' => 10,  //No. of Pages to show
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><font style="color:#666666;"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
<?php    the_content(__('Continue Reading'));             
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php
    global $paged;  
        if( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
            $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
        } elseif( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
            $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }

        $args = array(
            'post_type'     => 'page',
            'paged'         => $paged,
        );

        $blog_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <section>
        <?php if ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content-parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </section><!-- End #content -->
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have all the Page data stored in `$page_data`, you can pass the Page `ID` to the `get_permalink();` to get the permalink of each page inside foreach loop.

```
$pages = get_pages();
if ( !empty( $pages ) ) :
    foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
        $title = $page_data->post_title;
        $slug = $page_data->post_name;
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $page_data->ID ) . '">' . $title . '</a>';
        echo $slug;
        echo $content;
    }
endif;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is probably better ways to achieve what you are wanting, but to answer your question with what you have:

```
$permalink = get_the_permalink($page_data->ID);
```